# Getting banned with python script using API Telegram

Tags: python, api, telegram

I am doing a script that sends a message each 1 minute(aprox) to a bot, but over 2 hours the client telegram api blocks my script for 8 hours. Which is the max rate for this?

I read the API FAQS Telegram but it talks with 1 message/second and 20 messages/minutes

How could I fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not the Telegram API developer support.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I didn't see you in other similar posts saying this.

Comment: My Number is betting banned by Telegram now when using Telethon Python Library. Just after login its getting blocked